# What are the flaps on the exhaust of military airplanes for?

Tags: military, feature-identification, flaps, f-22

I have been looking over some pictures of military airplanes, and I noticed that some of the more modern air planes have flaps on the exhaust

[image: These are the flaps on the exhaust]

I was wondering if anyone knew what the purpose of the flaps were, and why they are only on modern airplanes

Comment: By flaps on exhaust, are you talking about [thrust vectoring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrust_vectoring)?

Comment: yes, i am talking about that...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Those *flaps on exhaust* are for [thrust vectoring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrust_vectoring). A simple definition would be:

> the ability of an aircraft [...] to manipulate the direction of the
>   thrust [...] to control the attitude [...] of the vehicle

F-22 uses it like [this](http://science.howstuffworks.com/f-22-raptor5.htm):

> [Its] nozzle [...] is the first vectoring nozzle. That means
>   the pilot can move, or vector, the nozzle up and down by 20 degrees.
>
> The gases coming out of the vector nozzle help push the airplane's
>   nose up or down. This vectoring increases the roll rate of the plane
>   by 50 percent, making it much more maneuverable than other fighters.
>
> Thrust vectoring [...] works automatically in response to commands
>   from the pilot.

Answer (score 5):

Adding to [the above answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/15438/8166):

These mechanical devises are for thrust vectoring.  Their *purpose* is for super-maneuverability, meaning that the aircraft can maintain pitch and yaw control at extreme angles of attack where other non super-maneuverable aircraft would stall, spin, completely loose control, etc.

This ultimately allows a wider flight envelope and the ability to "push the envelope" further than would be without thrust vectoring.

Thrust vectoring allows a plane to turn harder and faster because, rather than the control surfaces doing most of the work to turn the airframe, the engine exhaust becomes a large component in the vector change, thus reducing the load on the wings and the rest of the airframe.  Loading the wings with high g turns is dangerous beyond the flight envelope - the vectoring eases the load and thus widens the envelope.  Also, point the nozzles in opposing horizontal directions aids in rolling the aircraft.

Concerning your picture - the F-22 has '2D' thrust vectoring - allowing the exhaust to de deflected up and down over the horizontal axis and controlling *2 dimensions* of flight dynamics (pitch and roll).  Aircraft such as the MiG-29OVT (below) have '3D' thrust vectoring, allowing control of *3 dimensions* of flight dynamics (pitch, roll, and yaw).

[image]

I've heard the MiG's nozzles are sometimes referred to as 'flowers of steel' because of the way they open, close, and move, sometimes completely independently of each other.

The video below shows the beautiful 3D nozzles in action starting at 1:40

[Video: 3D Thrust Vectoring](https://youtu.be/y6RYQZzLWOk)

Comment: I'm not sure that 3D means what you think it means....

Comment: F22 is 1D,  Mig is 2D. you can't have 3D vectoring.

Comment: 3D means what I think it means.  @Federico, technically you're right, but that is what it's commonly known as in the military aviation community.  My guess is that the engineers settled on this nomenclature because the '2D' raptor nozzles can control 2 dimensions of flight dynamics (pitch and roll) whereas the MiG's '3D' vectoring can control 3 (pitch, roll, AND yaw).

Comment: @ebrohman fair enough

Comment: @Federico: The same illogical counting method goes on in redundancy: Triple redundancy means that two more systems are there when the primary system fails. This is actually only double redundancy, but everyone calls it "triple" redundancy. Get over it, i got used to it myself long ago.